# AJAX request can't read updated session/global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am using Flask with google-python-api-client to get data from Youtube.

I am trying to load asynchronously next video from the playlist when a button is pressed. For that I need to set the `nextPageToken` parameter when making the request

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#more_content').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/test",
                data: {np_token: '{{ g.np_token }}'},
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#content").append(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The function I am using to get the next video:

```
def get_another_video():
    res = YOUTUBE.playlistItems().list(
        part="snippet",
        playlistId=PLAYLIST_ID,
        maxResults="1",
        pageToken=request.args.get('np_token', None)
    ).execute()
    g.np_token = res.get('nextPageToken', None)
    return json.dumps(res)
```

This is not working because AJAX request cannot read the updated value from the global variable `g.np_token`, and the same result will be if I'll set a session variable.

How do I solve this problem? The passed parameters to AJAX will be available only in the case of a `success` request, but I need them to be accessible in the `data` part.

I've read that for this kind of task, redis or memcache might be suitable, but I don't know if I'll be able to access those variables in the templates.
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown enough information here. What function is responsible for originally rendering the template that contains that Ajax script? (Note that this problem doesn't actually appear to have anything to do with Ajax; and I can't see what redis or memcached would do here either.)

Comment: So, looks like when you are rendering the page, data: {np_token: '{{ g.np_token }}'}, is undefined?

Comment: @Paul, is defined, but it remains always the same, it is not updated when the token is updated in the function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have a function that renders the template, by calling the same function above.

Comment: That didn't help. Where are you passing that `g.np_token` variable to the template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `g.np_token` is not a template variable, it is a request-bound global variable

Comment: Well, that's exactly my point. Request-bound global variables are only available in the template if you use a RequestContext. Did you? We can't know, because you haven't shown the handler that rendered that template. In any case, as my answer points out, there doesn't seem to be any reason to use a global variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use a global variable - or any separate variable at all - for your token. It is passed back from the YouTube API, and you are in turn passing that whole response to your template. You can simply get it from there in your JS function and use the value on your next call.

```
var token;
$('#more_content').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/test",
        data: {np_token: token},
        success: function(result) {
            token = result['nextPageToken'];
            $("#content").append(result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

And what if you will update g.np_token in the `success` part?

Like this:

```
var np_token = null; 

function ajaxCallBack(token){
    np_token = token;
}
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/test",
    data: {np_token: '{{ g.np_token }}'},
    success: function(result) {
        $("#content").append(result);
        ajaxCallBack(response['token']);
    }
});
```